# Git rebase can't use notepad++ folder does not exist/git proceeds regardless of notepad++

Tags: git, notepad++

as titled.

git commit

git rebase -i

all are unsuccessful

Looking in process monitor I was able to see that notepad initially successfully reads the file and then in the mean time the folder is deleted. This is a strange behavior and I couldn't proceed from that. After setting notepad as default editor, this behavior was gone. So notepad++ was the issue

reinstalling notepad++

using full notepad++ path

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git%20notepad%2b%2b

Answer (score 1):

Step 1. use full path of notepad++

Step 2. add -multiInst for the argument for notepad++

```ini
[core]
    editor = \"C:/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe\" -multiInst -notabbar -nosession
```